# How do I create a JOIN between 2 SELECT Statements with GROUPs?

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have one table with daily stock data and I want to summarize it by week.  The daily table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempDaily] (
    [Symbol]    CHAR (10)  NOT NULL,
    [CloseDate] DATE       NOT NULL,
    [DailyHi]   FLOAT (53) NULL,
    [DailyLow]  FLOAT (53) NULL,
    [AdjClose]  FLOAT (53) NOT NULL,
    [WeekEnd]   DATE       NULL
);
```

I want to insert a summary for the week into the weekly table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Weekly] (
    [Symbol]    CHAR (10)  NOT NULL,
    [WeekEnd]   DATE       NOT NULL,
    [WeeklyHi]  FLOAT (53) NOT NULL,
    [WeeklyLow] FLOAT (53) NOT NULL,
    [AdjClose]  FLOAT (53) NULL
);
```

The [AdjClose] column is set to nulls allowed because my current workaround inserts the other 4 columns first, then updates the weekly table with the weekly AdjClose value from a 3rd table, which is really slow.

Getting the weekly data into the table for the first 4 columns is straightforward:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Weekly (Symbol, WeekEnd, WeeklyHi, WeeklyLow) " &
    "SELECT Symbol, WeekEnd, MAX(DailyHi), MIN(DailyLow) " &
     "FROM TempDaily " &
     "GROUP BY Symbol, WeekEnd "
```

Getting the weekly AdjClose is not as straightforward but I can insert the data into a temporary table and then update the Weekly table from it:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Test (WeekEnd, AdjClose) " &
    "Select wdata.WeekEnd, MAX(wdata.AdjClose) " &
    "FROM " &
        "(Select CloseDate, WeekEnd, " &
        "FIRST_VALUE(AdjClose) OVER (PARTITION BY WeekEnd ORDER BY CloseDate                                            
         DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) As AdjClose " &
         "FROM TempDaily) wdata " &
     "GROUP BY wdata.WeekEnd "
```

I would really prefer to insert the data for all 5 columns into the Weekly table with a single statement rather than resorting to my clumsy workaround but I haven't been able to figure out how to join the 2 statements.

The data from the Daily table is in the format (spaces added for clarity):

```
Symbol,    CloseDate,  DailyHi,DailyLow,AdjClose,   WeekEnd
AAPL      ,5/31/2019,   177.99,  175.00,  175.07,  6/1/2019
AAPL      ,5/30/2019,   179.23,  176.67,  178.30,  6/1/2019
AAPL      ,5/29/2019,   179.35,  176.00,  177.38,  6/1/2019
AAPL      ,5/28/2019,   180.59,  177.91,  178.23,  6/1/2019
AAPL      ,5/24/2019,   182.14,  178.62,  178.97,  5/25/2019
AAPL      ,5/23/2019,   180.54,  177.81,  179.66,  5/25/2019
AAPL      ,5/22/2019,   185.71,  182.55,  182.78,  5/25/2019
AAPL      ,5/21/2019,   188.00,  184.70,  186.60,  5/25/2019
AAPL      ,5/20/2019,   184.35,  180.28,  183.09,  5/25/2019
```

The weekly table should end up with:

```
Symbol,        WeekEnd, WeeklyHi, WeeklyLo,  AdjClose
AAPL      ,   6/1/2019,   180.59,   175.00,   175.07
AAPL      ,   5/25/2019,  188.00,   177.81,   178.97
```

I'm converting a MS Access database into VB.NET and thought it would be a fairly simple port.  There are a lot more differences than I anticipated.  Any help is appreciated.

The solution presented below is one I'd tried but it generates an SQLException: 'Incorrect syntax near '('.  Incorrect syntax near 'wdata'.  So I'm still trying to figure this one out.

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Weekly (Symbol, WeekEnd, WeeklyHi, WeeklyLow, AdjClose) " &
"Select A.Symbol, A.WeekEnd, A.WeeklyHi, A.WeeklyLow, ISNULL(B.AdjClose, 0) as AdjClose " &
"FROM " &
    "(SELECT Symbol, WeekEnd, MAX(DailyHi) as WeeklyHi, MIN(DailyLow) as WeeklyLow " &
     "FROM TempDaily " &
     "GROUP BY Symbol, WeekEnd ) A " &
     "LEFT JOIN " & 
    "(Select wdata.WeekEnd, MAX(wdata.AdjClose) as AdjClose" &
    "FROM " &
        "(Select CloseDate, WeekEnd, " &
        "FIRST_VALUE(AdjClose) OVER (PARTITION BY WeekEnd ORDER BY CloseDate                                            
         DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) As AdjClose " &
         "FROM TempDaily) wdata " &
     "GROUP BY wdata.WeekEnd) B ON A.WeekEnd = B.WeekEnd "
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Your problem is a code extension not returning what you expect. Make it clear that your question is about *that error* & ask re your overall goal later in a new post. PS Caclulate separate aggregations then join them a common PK/UNIQUE.

Comment: So, what is strSQL? PS `AdjClose" &  "FROM "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can do what you want, joining them like this (updated):

```
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Weekly (Symbol, WeekEnd, WeeklyHi, WeeklyLow, AdjClose) " &
"Select A.Symbol, A.WeekEnd, A.WeeklyHi, A.WeeklyLow, ISNULL(B.AdjClose, 0) as AdjClose " &
"FROM " &
    "(SELECT Symbol, WeekEnd, MAX(DailyHi) as WeeklyHi, MIN(DailyLow) as WeeklyLow " &
    "FROM TempDaily " &
    "GROUP BY Symbol, WeekEnd ) A " &
    "LEFT JOIN " &
    "(Select wdata.WeekEnd, MAX(wdata.AdjClose) as AdjClose " &
    "FROM " &
        "(Select CloseDate, WeekEnd, " &
        "FIRST_VALUE(AdjClose) OVER (PARTITION BY WeekEnd ORDER BY CloseDate " &
        "DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) As AdjClose " &
        "FROM TempDaily) wdata " &
     "GROUP BY wdata.WeekEnd) B ON A.WeekEnd = B.WeekEnd "
```

Comment: Yes, I've missed a couple of quotation marks. Just updated.